# How angular application gets loaded/initiated? How do app components template is loaded in index.html?

Tags: angular

1. How angular (not angularjs) application gets loaded/initiated?
2. How do app components template is loaded in index.html?

Comment: Its injected by  `webpack`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**How Angular Application Gets Initiated**](https://programingsoeasy.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-angular-app-gets-loaded-our-browser.html)
article explains complete flow and steps of how angular application gets initiated.

Our Browser shows a lot of content and there’s not a trace of it in index.html.
How is this happening? What’s with this weird app-root tag too?

**Root Component:**
app-root  is one of our own Component which CLI created for us.
Wait, what?
I know I haven’t spoken about Component at all and I will dive deeper into in next article, but before that let’s try to resolve this mystery of where the content is being loaded.
Let’s talk about root component which Chotu created for us, the app component which lies in src/app folder.
 app.component.ts somewhat solves the text-mystery. We see a selector tag which is named app-root, the same text which was present in index.html.
app.component.html hold the text template which we see in the browser.

Clearly, there seems to be some connection between index.html and app components.

But, how do app components template is loaded in index.html? Let’s find out.
If we look at the source code in our browser, we see there are few script files automatically injected at the bottom(like inline.bundle.js), which we didn’t see in raw index.html file.

These files are bundled when we hit ng serve CLI command and added automatically in index.html. They contain all the codes we write in the app folder.
So, the first file which gets executed during ng serve is from file name main.ts.
Main File Of Angular – main.ts
Main.ts has a bunch of imports at the top but we’ve to specifically look that line which starts our application where we pass AppModule to the method which is part of app.module.ts
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)

Closer Look at App.module.ts :
The app.module.ts file has a bootstrap array which holds AppComponent, same root component which had that weird app-root tag. Here, we reference that AppComponent which then renders its app.component.html file into index.html.

**Step 1:** main.ts file gets loaded. It bootstraps(starts) the application by calling App.module.file.

**Step 2:** app.module.ts file holds an array of bootstrap components. Here, we find our root component reference.

**Step 3:** Root component gets loaded and the template files from app.component.html become part of index.html.

Answer (score 3):

1. Angular app get loaded with the help of bootstrap. You can check it in main.ts. With the help of System.js(angular 2/4) and Webpack(angular 5) it gets loaded.
2. If you will check the Appmodule. You can see the property bootstrap inside @ngModule. It tells the first component to get load. In index.html you must have a selector of the component loaded in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

When an Angular app is loaded and started, the following steps occur :-

1. The browser loads the `index.html` file, which is the entry point for the application.
2. The `index.html` file contains a script tag that references the main Javascript bundle for the application. This bundle contains all of the Angular framework code, as well as the applications own code.
3. The browser loads and executes the main Javascript bundle.
4. The main Javascript bundle bootstraps the Angular application by calling the `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.error(err));` method which is present in `main.ts` file. This method takes the applications root module as a parameter.
5. The root module is responsible for configuring the Angular application and providing it's root component.
6. The Angular application creates an instance of the root component and renders it to the DOM.